# If state check for object property that is not always there breaks the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, if-statement, getjson

I am building a weather app. The user submits a zip code or city name + state and off the $.getJSON function goes.

The function I am trying to implement is to check if the user gave a bad value. For example, if the user inputs `New York, New York`, `Baltimore` or `90210` then the user will get the forecast. However, if the user inputs something wrong like `999999999` that cannot be found, then the user should be alerted and the function should reset the input for the user to try again.

I thought that if statements didn't always need an else which would allow me to get by. The problem is that for a properly formatted request, `data.response.error.description` does not exist so the function gets hung up and quits. **How can I get around if this object property does not exist?** I tried with some `else` statements but that only seemed to check for `data.response.error.description` to equal something else.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/7434225907cbf087/forecast/q/';
var userInput;
var end = '.json';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#myDiv').html("");
    userInput = ($('#input').val());
    $.getJSON(url + userInput + end, function(data) {
      console.log("user input: " + userInput);
      console.log(data);
      if (data.response.error.description ==
        "No cities match your search query") {
        $('#input').val("");
        alert("Your input was incorrect, try again!");
        return;
      };

      $('#userSubmission').html("");
      $('#userSubmission').html(userInput);
      //var highFahrenheit = data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit;
      //console.log(data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0])
      //console.log(highFahrenheit);
      $('#myDiv').html("Today's high is " + highFahrenheit +
        " degrees Fahrenheit");
    });
    $('#input').val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Location" id="input">
<div id="userSubmission"></div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="verify"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you check for a sub-property, check that the containing property exists:

```
if (data.response && data.response.error && data.response.error.description == "No cities match your search query")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `data.response`, `data.hasOwnProperty("response")` can tell you if `data` has a key named `response` in it or not.

If it has the function will return `true` else will return `false`.

Go on in a forward manner to ensure it never breaks.

```
data &&
data.hasOwnProperty("response") &&       
data.response.hasOwnProperty("error") &&
data.response.error.hasOwnProperty("description") &&
data.response.error.description == "No cities match your search query"
```

Will never break.

Comment: The argument to `hasOwnProperty` must be a string. And you can't use a dotted property name.

Comment: @Barmar My bad, i dont how why i did that, must be because of hurry. :( Check now.

Comment: Better. Although for most purposes, the simpler version in my answer will suffice. It's also not necessary to test whether the `description` property exists; if it doesn't, it will be `undefined`, and it won't match the test string.